# how to assign two value condition in form group field?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
     this.form = this.fb.group({
       id:[],
      name: [ details.name|| '' ] 
})
```

Can we assign value in form like if details.name is there name field should take details.name or if details.name is empty it should take null.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  'id':new FormControl(''),
  'name':new FormControl(''),
});


if(details.name){
    this.form.controls.name.patchValue(details.name);
}
```

Comment: its throwing error -- Cannot read property of 'get' of undefined type error

Comment: this line worked for me in my code  `this.form.controls.name.patchValue(details.name);`

Comment: @Sahil cool! can you mark the answer as correct? so other people can benefit from it